# _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been notified by this error all the time

```
final authRepositoryProvider = Provider(
  (ref) => AuthRepository(
    firestore: ref.read(firestoreProvider),
    auth: ref.read(authProvider),
    googleSignIn: ref.read(googleSignInProvider),
  ),
);

// A class that handles authentication related operations
class AuthRepository {
  // Instance of Firestore for database operations
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore;

  final FirebaseAuth _auth; // Instance of FirebaseAuth for authentication
  final GoogleSignIn
      _googleSignIn; // Instance of GoogleSignIn for Google authentication

  // Constructor to initialize the AuthRepository with required instances
  AuthRepository({
    required FirebaseFirestore firestore,
    required FirebaseAuth auth,
    required GoogleSignIn googleSignIn,
  })  : _auth = auth,
        _firestore = firestore,
        _googleSignIn = googleSignIn;

  CollectionReference get _users =>
      _firestore.collection(FirebaseConstants.usersCollection);

  Stream<User?> get authStateChange => _auth.authStateChanges();

  // Method to sign in using Google authentication
  FutureEither<UserModel> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser =
          await _googleSignIn.signIn(); // Start Google sign-in process

      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: (await googleUser?.authentication)?.accessToken,
        idToken: (await googleUser?.authentication)?.idToken,
      );
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(
          credential); //This will allow us to store the credentials in the firebase

      UserModel userModel;

      if (userCredential.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser) {
        userModel = UserModel(
          name: userCredential.user!.displayName ?? "No Name",
          profilePic: userCredential.user!.photoURL ?? Constants.avatarDefault,
          banner: Constants.bannerDefault,
          uid: userCredential.user!.uid,
          isAuthenticated: true,
          karma: 0,
          awards: [],
        );
        await _users.doc(userCredential.user!.uid).set(userModel.toMap());
      } else {
        userModel = await getUserData(userCredential.user!.uid).first;
      }
      return right(userModel);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw e.message!;
    } catch (e) {
      return Left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }

// stream is used for Real-time Data Synchronization

  Stream<UserModel> getUserData(String uid) {
    return _users.doc(uid).snapshots().map(
        (event) => UserModel.fromMap(event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
  }

s.
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dta66.png)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I have tried some solutions by searching in chatGpt but nothing worked.
The Error is _TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast).
what's wrong i my code.

Comment: Where are you declaring the List variable in your code? Over there, try declaring the variable as `List<String> xyz = [];` instead of `List xyz = [];`

Comment: It means in your `UserModel` there's a list which is of type `List<dynamic>` and should be of type `List<String>.` look for this kind of type in your `UserModel`